# How to build a 'negative list' with crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports

I just started to use crystal report and struggling about some kind of negative list building.
I am getting two input lists into crystal report and as a result I like to output a list of items, which are not included in both lists. 
Example:

```
List 1 contains Peter, John, Alice, Mary and Tom
List 2 contains Peter and Mary
My result list should show John, Alice and Tom
```

How can I do this with crystal report?

Answer (score 0):

If by LIST you mean database table, use an Outer Join from A to B and apply a record selection criterion of:  IsNull(B.some_column)

Comment: Unfortunately I have no direct access to the DB, only a combined report table, more or less an inner join of both lists. And I also found no possiblity to formulate such kind of sql statement. From google results it also seems that my crystal report has only a restricted feature set. I can only find some of the things in the tool which I find in the documentation...